# Output of `git stash show` empty

Tags: git, git-stash

I have an upgrade script that runs

```sh
git stash -k -u
```

Before updating to the newest version.

Normally, this outputs: `No local changes to save`
But since some time, it has been outputting: `Saved working directory and index state WIP on generated: build` even though no changes were made to the working copy.

When I try to inspect the contents of any of the stashes, it appears completely empty, too:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on generated: bc0c9f6 build
stash@{1}: WIP on generated: 1d83819 build
stash@{2}: WIP on generated: 6aff261 build
stash@{3}: WIP on generated: ac3f8a9 build
stash@{4}: WIP on generated: bf0d020 build
stash@{5}: WIP on generated: ba972db build
stash@{6}: WIP on generated: 2c5cfe3 build

$ git stash show stash@{0}
$ git stash show stash@{1}
```

Etc... the output is empty for all stashes. Same if I specify the `-p` flag to the `stash show` command.

I need help figuring out the contents of these stashes in order to speculate why they are being created in the first place.

Comment: Maybe your `show` is not sufficient. Of course there is no difference from the last _commit_ but that is not what you want to know.

Comment: I don’t know why `git stash show` doesn’t show diffs for entirely new files and can’t look it up now, but I do know how to fix it if that is the issue: `git show stash@{0}`

Comment: @Ry- this still shows me what appears to be an empty diff

see: https://gist.github.com/sgtlambda/59f942e8f1dbdf61496033deb1774dfc

Comment: @matt would you elaborate on that some more? I've always had it in my mind stashes are more of less completely independent collections of changes?

Answer (score 4):

A stash is actually just a commit, or more precisely, two or three commits (depending on the stash options).  Since you are using `-u`, you get the three-commit variant.

I call the three commits `i`, `w`, and (when present) `u`.  The `i` commit is made by committing the index contents, the same way `git commit` would, except that the commit does not go onto any branch.

The `u` commit, if present, contains only untracked-but-not-ignored files (with `-u`; with `-a` it contains more files).  Having made this `u` commit, Git then removes from your work-tree any files stored in this commit.

The `w` commit is always made last, and contains the same *set of files* (file names) as are present in the `i` commit, but the *contents of those files* in the `w` commit match the content in your work-tree copies of those files, rather than the content in the index copies.

When `git stash` *without* `-u` finds no differences between the `HEAD` commit, the current index, and your work-tree files that have the names of the copies that are in the index, `git stash` refuses to make a new stash, producing instead the error message you mentioned (`No local changes to save`).  If you do have untracked files, though, it should make the stash and then remove those untracked files.  This will result in a stash in which the `i` and `w` contents match, and both match the commit that was `HEAD` at the time you ran `git stash`.

The `git stash` command was rewritten in a recent Git and some of its edge case behaviors may have changed.  If so, this is a bug, and you should report it to the Git community (ideally, with a reproducer and the specific Git versions in which the behaviors differ).

Note that `git stash show` simply looks at the `w` commit.  Like all commits, all three of the `i`, `u`, and `w` commits can have *parent commits*.  The (single) parent of the `i` commit is the commit that was current at the time you made the stash.  The `u` commit, if it exists, is a root commit (has no parent).  The `w` commit has either two or three parents: the first one is the commit that was current at the time you made the stash, the second is the `i` commit, and the third, if present, is the `u` commit.  That is, we can draw the commit graph like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
            /
           u
```

The name `stash` (full name `refs/stash`) points to the `w` commit.  The current branch, here `current-branch` (full name `refs/heads/current-branch`) points to the current commit, and the special name `HEAD` is attached to the name `current-branch` so that Git can find commit `H`'s hash ID.

Commit `H` is therefore the parent of `i`, and the first parent of `w`.  Git detects the presence, or absence, of commit `u` by whether `w` has a third parent.

`git stash show -p` is equivalent to `git diff stash stash~1`, i.e., compares the contents of the files in commit `H` to those in commit `w`.  If the reason for making the stash is that `u` exists, or that `i` differs from `i~1`, there is no need for `w` to differ from `w~1`.

Comment: You can add : run `git show stash@{xx}^3` to view the untracked files which may have been stored

Comment: @LeGEC: good point; you can also use `git show stash@{number}^2` to view a diff of the `i` commit vs its parent (`H` in the diagram in the answer above). Because the `w` commit has the form of a merge commit, though, you need `git stash show` (or `git diff`) to view it with respect to its first parent.

Comment: Brilliant answer @torek!